# Download Restcomm binary distribution

Tags: restcomm

Where is the place to download the Last JBOSS Restcomm Release?

Or What is the best way to get the Last Release? Docker?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to run the latest release is Docker as @Alex Hales mentioned.

If you want to contribute the latest binary release is available from https://github.com/RestComm/RestComm-Core/releases/latest and build it from source is http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-mobicents-building-from-source/

Answer (score 2):

You can see documentation related to Docker at this link: http://www.telestax.com/rapid-webrtc-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker/